# Count the number of classes an element has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you were to label elements by some [tag] system, likely attached by the user, and you wanted to count the number of tags (defined by the number of classes the element has), how would you accomplish this?

This could be beneficial if you were to try to review all elements by number of tags.   (This likely could be accomplished by other structures, but if you were to only reference the element tags in this way)

Jquery has .hasClass(), is there something like .classCount()

Comment: the question i will ask before answering is, how did you try this?

Comment: trying to think of ways to review elements by the count of classes (again assuming that the classes mean user feedback). And, trying to avoid functions, but i would use one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create it...

```
$.fn.classCount = function() {
    return $.grep(this.attr("class").split(/\s+/), $.trim).length;
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPCE6/).

If you don't have jQuery, you could use...

```
var classLength = element.classList.length;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUT9q/).

If you don't have jQuery *and* have to support the older browsers, go with...

```
var classes = element.className.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").split(/\s+/);
var classLength = classes[0].length ? classes.length : 0;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NAHf/).

Comment: May I ask what this does? $.grep

Comment: @VIDesignz It drops empty matches.

Comment: Maybe explain this a bit instead? return $.grep(this.attr("class").split(/\s+/), $.trim).length;

Comment: Without knowing exactly, I would say you are finding the classes of this (the div) splitting them up wherever there is spaces, dont know what the trim does and I assume the .length is the count of the classes after all the other fancy work...am I close?

Comment: The $.trim deals with if there are multiple spaces at the beginning and/end of a string, in this case, the class list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [classList attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) if you are using HTML5. For example

```
$("#someElementId").classList.length
```

would return 2 for:

```
<div id="someElementId" class="stinky cheese"></div>
```

as in http://jsfiddle.net/thegreatmichael/rpdEr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sWWAH/1)**

Comment: This will give the wrong answer if there is multiple spaces separating class names. Sometimes it happens, and I think it's worth defending against that case.